# Any folder copied to my Flash/memory card becomes a shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, anti-virus

When I copy any folder to my memory card, it becomes a shortcut and the attributes of that folder changes to protected operating system files (hidden). I've formatted my memory card completely, have scanned it using two antivirus programs but the problem remains the same. Can somebody solve this problem that my folder's shortcut is not created when I paste into my memory card. Because the hidden files are not accessible in phone.

**Additional Details:**

If there is virus. How to delete that virus, I've scanned it with two antivirus programs (Microsoft Essentials and AVAST Free). I've formatted that as well but no benefit.

Comment: I have seen this behavior before, it is a virus, specifically a rootkit. Run tdsskiller to find it. If i recall correctly the folder shortcut icon is actually an executable file to spread the virus.

Comment: @RichieFrame Experience is a valuable thing. This sounds like key information for the OP. Why not post this as an answer and give a link to any information you have on it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have any details on this, i was a while ago, and I believe it was a rather old rootkit at that time, if I can find any info I will definitely answer it

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [solution](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-446905-all-the-folder-in-my-pendrive-become-shortcut):

f you did not format your flash drive, then check whether the files are not in hidden mode.

Click on `Start` --> `Run` --> type `cmd` and click on `OK`.

Here I assume your pendrive as G:

Enter this command.

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d G:\*.*
```

Note : Replace the letter `G` with your flash drive letter.  Now check for your files in drive.

After that, download the Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware [from here](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-105-malwarebytes-anti-malware):

```
Update it --> Perform "Full Scan"
```

Note: Default selected option is "Quick Scan".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Symantec's free tools `Norton Power Eraser`:

https://security.symantec.com/nbrt/npe.aspx

On first launch, it asks to restart the computer before scanning for bad stuffs. When it finish scanning and if anything found, it offers "Remove". Then a reboot, it scans again to confirm the removal. Neat.

In the mean time, have you tried zipping the files you want to copy to media card on to local partition, then from the zip program, unzip to the media card? Sometimes bad ware cannot hook programs other than explorer.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Kaspersky's TDSSKiller if problem persists after format. This tool will detect and remove rootkits.

http://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/TDSSKiller

Comment: It might be better to include Richie Frame's comment in your answer. Now it's not clear why you are jumping to rootkit.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt, it is a virus. First of all update your Avast virus definition and perform a boot time scan on your system. Avast will find some virus for sure, first try to fix them automatically. If it doesn't worked repair them, and if the two procedures don't worked delete it.

After the scan copy the files to flash/memory card. There will be shortcut problem this time. If there is a shorcut problem, just do the following steps:

- Open cmd(Win+R --> Typt cmd --> Hit Enter)
- Now suppose your memory card is G drive. Then type 'G:' (without inverted comas). Hit Enter.
- Now type 'attrib -h -s /d /s' (without inverted comas). Hit Enter and wait for it to complete.

Now open your memory card from My Computer and see whether there are anything other than shortcuts. If there is all you want, just delete the shortcuts. Thinks it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let go of your <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while you're dragging. If the system thinks it's being pressed, the default action (when dragging) is to create a link (or shortcut). If your <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is not physically pressed on your keyboard, ensure Sticky Keys is turned off, check for any extra keyboards plugged in, and just try tapping the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on each side, in case it got sticky.